# Strange behaviour of scrollviewer in tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I have following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Items>
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>tabItem1</TabItem.Header>
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Image Source="RentgenogramOfWrist.jpg" Width="500"></Image>
                            <Button Width="300" Height="300"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>tabItem2</TabItem.Header>
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Image Source="RentgenogramOfWrist.jpg" Width="500"></Image>
                            <Button Width="300" Height="300"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl.Items>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that when program is running and I switch to second tabItem scrollViewer will be scrolled to start of button. When I now switch from second tabItem to first one the same happenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button`'s `Focusable` property is [true by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable(v=vs.110).aspx), so the `ScrollViewer` scrolls to focus the button.

Set

```
<Button Width="300" Height="300" Focusable="False"/>
```

for one of them and see what changes.